# Alternative syntax for control structures in PHP

Tags: php

I have a very short code snippet but I have been unable to get the result I want. The code is as shown

```
<?php
$user = true;
if($user==true): ?>
<p>you are already logged in</p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>User value is not set</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

on running the code it gives this error:`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)`

What might be the problem?

Comment: [Seems to work well enough](https://3v4l.org/VHlD1)

Comment: its working properly...

Comment: And why is it giving an error on my machine? maybe it something to do with php installation. Thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your editor. I had similar problems (more than once) with Atom.

To solve, I just copied the file contents, closed it, reopened, pasted the contents and saved.

The code is fine, as others mentioned in the comments. You should try out this.

Answer (score 0):

@lil your code is looks right only, this is alternate way to get same output if you like you can try this.

```
<?php
$user = true;
if($user==true)
{
?>
    <p>you are already logged in</p>
<?php 
}
else
{
 ?>
    <p>User value is not set</p>
<?php
 } ?>
```